# Flutter Calculate Height of RichText Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a Column that holds an array of Container Widgets. The Height of one of these Container Widgets is dependent on the Heigth of the Rich Text Widget it holds, for better understanding here is a screenshot:

[image]

I want the History Container to be the same height as all the other ones, is there an elegant solution to do this?

Comment: You would be setting the font size of that text somewhere inside of the RichText widget. Move those font sizes up in the code hierarchy so they can be used to calculate the height of the Container that holds them. Is there a reason you cannot do this? Can you provide a functioning example of your code?

Comment: There is no reason why I can't do that, I just cant figure out how to get the height of a textspan

Comment: The TextSpan is the height of the text within it. `TextSpan(text: "hello, world.", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16))` => It will be at least 16 high. You can try to use a `GlobalKey` on the TextSpan element and use the `RenderBox` of it's context to get the height of the control.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a fixed height to a container ! and set text to fit in one line `Text('Name',maxLines: 1,),` so it will take same height in all row.
or
Alternatively you can add a empty Text widget as subtitle(grey one) in History row.
like -> `Text(" ", style:TextStyle())` Give it same style as other subtitle. as result Text widget will take it space like other but wont be visible to UI.

Answer (score 0):

By wrapping every widget on your `Column` with an `Expanded` widget, they will *all* share the same height.